# Android - Google Maps - Calculate distance between two locations (LatLng)

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to calculate the distance in Kilometer(Km) of the two geopoints that is stored in FirebaseFirestore. I will use the Km data to formulate my freigth algoritm. Google maps can do it, but I dont know what api to use. Distance api or Directions api.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTGXK.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can use Directions api, in example JSON you have 'distance' object between two points:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start?csw=1#sample-request

The one thing I would suggest is to check if 'legs' key, which is an array, contains more than one object and if you need to run for loop to collect all of the distances. Probably the case is valid when you have more than one point on your route

Comment: Thanks, I see, google may suggest multiple routes with multiple distances. I may loop it and maybe use the shortest route.

Comment: Sure thing! I think distance is returned in meters, but you should check it documentation because I'm writing from my memory